# How do I get nearby hospitals on Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps

How do I get nearby hospitals on Google Maps?

I have the current position's latitude and longitude. How can i find nearby hospitals locations using only android and google maps api .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display custom places in Google Maps API search results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824133/how-to-display-custom-places-in-google-maps-api-search-results)

Comment: Blatantly off-topic (has nothing to do with programming)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can get places near by your location using [Google Place API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/?csw=1) and for use of [Place Api](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/google-play-services-using-the-places-api--cms-23715) see this blog. hope this will help